# How to work with MyQL and CodeIgniter in Pagodabox

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagoda-box

I am new to Pagodabox. I have a PHP CodeIgniter application. I am successfully uploaded the files. I have created the tunnel connection. Now how do connect with the database and retrieve data?

Comment: Did you check you the [Codeignier demo running on Pagoda Box](https://github.com/pagodabox/codeigniter-demo) or [this](https://github.com/pagodabox/codeigniter-install) at github?

Comment: the problem is how am I going to deploy the database i have in my phpmyadmin in pagodabox. and how do I connect with it from my codeigniter app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pagodabox, they've changed the `database.php` file in the demo, you might want to consider: https://github.com/pagodabox/codeigniter-demo/blob/master/application/config/database.php